# Import .jar to IntelliJ Java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, import

I made a customised data structures class library and I want to pack it as a .jar file and then use it on another project. My IDE is IntelliJ.

How can I make the .jar file and then import it on my other project?

Comment: Intellij has an artifact section in the project settings.  You can have an artifact of type jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the project that you want to pack as a `jar`.
2. Go to **File -> Project structure**.
3. Select the **Artifacts** menu.
4. Click on the green plus and select **JAR -> From modules with dependencies...** click **Apply** and then **OK**.
5. Go to **Build -> Build artifacts... -> Build**
6. Copy the `.jar` file that can be found in `out/artifacts/<name>/<name>.jar`
7. Open your other project where you want to use your `jar` file.
8. Create a folder named `lib/` and put your `jar` file there.
9. Go to **File -> Project structure**.
10. Select the **Modules** menu on the left and the **Dependencies** tab.
11. Click the green plus on the right side, select **JARs or directories...** and then select your `jar` file.
12. You are ready to go.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's exactly what I needed